# create-react-app + npm start - 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

Similar questions that I have tried following

["npm-run-all" is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54525742/npm-run-all-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

["'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47928735/react-scripts-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

I am trying to create a React project via the create-react-app cli, but after creating the project I get the error

```
'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"
```

when I try to launch the dev server via npm start.

What I have tried:

1) Make sure Node and npm are installed and up to date. From the project directory I run (via powershell)

```
> npm -v
6.7.0
> node -v
v11.11.0
```

2) Ensure that 'react-scripts' is listed with the correct version number in package.json

```
"name": "clipd2",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.5"
 },
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }...
```

3) Delete node_modules folder and package-lock.json and reinstall npm packages

```
rm -r -fo node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm install
npm install -S react-scripts
```

After instalation the react-scripts directory is found (and populated) in node_modules

4) Make sure npm is in the environment PATH variable

```
> echo $Env:Path
....C:\Users\notMyUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

I am at a loss for next steps. Strangely enough, I have another React app housed in the same parent directory

```
clipdReact
    clipd
    clipd2
```

And there are no problems when using npm start in the clipd project (whereas the failing project is clipd2)

Any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE

This bug was filed but is still open 
[react-scripts is not recognized](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6603)

You can start the dev server (from your project's directory) with

```
.\node_modules\.bin\react-scripts start
```

Be careful generating the production build with a command similar to the one above - I had problems with babel and polyfills when trying to do so.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54525742/npm-run-all-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/54526796#54526796 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["npm-run-all" Is Not Recognized As an Internal or External Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54525742/npm-run-all-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: @MattHolland I don't want to install react-scripts globally as it is explicitly stated here
[link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2436#issuecomment-306830791)
that it is a poor solution. 
npm start is already a defined script, so I do not believe I should need to redefine it. Also, the path to npm is in my PATH variable, as per the second answer in that question. Unless there is something that I missed here I do not believe it to be a duplicate.

Comment: @ihunter2839 did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @DanielKotin 
I filed this bug report [react-scripts is not recognized](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6603)

I start the dev server from the project folder with 
`.\node_modules\.bin\react-scripts start`
I tried to run a similar command to the one above to generate the production build and experience spurious errors with babel/transpliers and have resorted to building on a linux machine. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me in the end, was setting the script shell to powershell. The command for that is `npm config set script-shell powershell` and `npm config delete script-shell` to reset the config. I'm not sure why that worked, my guess is that since there are always 3 script files in `node_modules\.bin` that somehow the wrong shell was used for the wrong script or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install react-scripts --save --force
```

Answer (score 0):

When ever you see: 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

ANS:
npm install react-scripts --save

After it's done, type "npm start".

It'll work