# npm start fails after creating a new react project using create-react-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, create-react-app, react-scripts

I'm having some trouble with react-scripts after creating a new react project.
I created/initialised the project using `npx create-react-app dashboard`.
After going inside the dashboard folder and running `npm start` (without doing anything else beforehand), I get the following error:

```
>npm start
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> dashboard@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have checked the package.json file and it does have react-scripts listed (v5.0.1, full package.json below) and checking the node_modules folder shows a react-scripts folder there and react-scripts files (cmd, ps1 and 1 with no extension) inside the .bin folder too.

I've tried clearing the npm cache (`npm cache clean -f`), installing things again (deleting package-lock.json and node_modules folder then running `npm install`) and nothing seems to change.

I've also tried running `npm start` in command prompt, powershell and powershell as an admin. I've also tried restarting my PC and retrying too without any luck.

```
Specs:
Edition: Windows 10 Pro
Version: 21H2
OS build: 19044.1766
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack: 120.2212.4180.0
Node JS version: 16.15.1
npm version: 8.11.0
```

full package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this, I'd appreciate the help. Let me know if you need/want any more info that might help debug this issue

Comment: Try running with admin access to cmd.

Comment: @Nitika running `npm start`, `npx create-react-app` or both?

Comment: Running both commands as admin didn't help, same error is returned

Comment: How about [any of these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47928735/react-scripts-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)? [Or here?](https://exerror.com/react-scripts-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68394617/2371266, running `npm config set script-shell powershell` seems to have worked. I tried deleting the script-shell config afterwards and retrying and got the original error again so I'm assuming it is defaulting to something else and that's making things freak out a bit. I guess I'll just keep it pointed at powershell for now.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem as you, and this helped me solve it, just try installing

> react-scripts

on your project:

```
npm install react-scripts
```

just like that you are good to go!!!!